# imageJpeg and FFMPEG in windows vs linux

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, windows-10, redhat

I have a working code for converting image to a 5 seconds video using FFMPEG.

The problem is, The code only works for downloaded images, FFMPEG doesn't convert image to video when image is generated programmatically ONLY IN LINUX.

**PHP code**

```
<?php
    $downloadedF="folder/d.jpg";
    $downloadedV="folder/d.mp4";
    $renderedF="folder/r.jpg";
    $renderedV="folder/r.mp4";

    $op_d=shell_exec("ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i ".$downloadedF." -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p ".$downloadedV);
    $op_r=shell_exec("ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i ".$renderedF." -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 -pix_fmt yuv420p ".$renderedV);

    echo "Errors:<br>".$op_d."<br><br>".$op_r;
?>
```

The d.mp4(or output for downloaded image) is getting generated for both Windows and Linux
The r.mp4(or output for rendered image) gets generated only in Windows and 48 bytes empty file is getting created in Linux

**System:**

XAMPP on Windows 10(Development)
Godaddy Starter plan hosting - Linux(Probably redhat)(Production)

**File Structure**

```
root folder
    |-index.php
    |-ffmpeg (will be ffmpeg.exe in Windows)
    |-folder
        |-d.jpg (random downloaded image from google)
        |-d.mp4 (Will be created - video converted from downloaded image)
        |-r.jpg (rendered image using php imagejpg)
        |-r.mp4 (Will be created - video converted from rendered image)
```

**Rendered Image Code:**

```
$imgFF = imagecreatetruecolor($videoWidth, $videoHeight);
//---adding many text using imagettftext();
imagejpeg($imgFF, $path."-000.jpg");  //for this example, I copied output to folder as r.jpg
```

**Edit 1:**

The return value of `shell_exec` has no error/output even after adding

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Edit 2:**

The log for successful conversion can be found at [Here](https://pastebin.com/dSFe4wNm)
The log for unsuccessful conversion of rendered image can be found at [Here](https://pastebin.com/PfgfkF8E)

**Note:**

• The scenario here is minimized and code is separated from long code.
• In Linux command i add `./` for FFMPEG

Comment: Share full log for failing command on linux.

Comment: The shell_exec command or the script is not producing any errors. I have updated my question see "Edit 1"

Comment: Add -report and share report file. It is created in pwd of ffmpeg process.

Comment: Hi, I have added logs. Please see Edit 2